# How to automate tmux setup from shell script?

Tags: tmux

I'd like to setup my tmux session from a shell script.

essentially I want to automate something like:

Create a session, split the window vertically, create a new window, run command 1 in the first vertical split, command 2 in the second, and another command in the second window.

Is that possible? So far I am trying to send keys but I'm not sure if there is a better way.

```
tmux new-session -s foo -d
tmux new-window -t foo
tmux send -t foo.0 "echo 1" ENTER
tmux send -t foo.1 "echo 2" ENTER
tmux attach -t foo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to later kill the program you are running and be left with a shell, then send-keys is the best bet.

If you don't, you can just start the program directly as part of new-session or new-window, for example:

```
tmux new-session -sfoo -d -- top
tmux new-window -tfoo -- emacs
tmux attach -tfoo
```

The remain-on-exit option is also useful for running programs like this.